# Command exec and php shell_exec have different results

Tags: php, centos, cups

I am trying to create a print server using PHP - Lumen using Cups on a CentOS 7.

The result of `lpstat -p -d` in my command shell is :

> ```
>  printer ZTC_GK420t is idle.  enabled since Thu Apr 25 17:50:41 2019
>  no system default destination
> ```

The result of a php script :

```
$output = shell_exec("lpstat -p -d");
```

Is :

> ```
>      Array
> (
>     [0] => no system default destination
>     [1] => 
> )
> ```

What could be the cause of this? I have the same results with PHP exec() & system().

The code is working as expected on a MacOs

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that may make results different here is the difference of privileges available to the user in your shell and the user PHP running under .

Comment: I tried changing folder permission to apache but it doesn't change anything. And https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php give me root as user, i am also using root on the terminal